# Angularjs default value of radio button is not working

Tags: angularjs, listbox, radio-button, default-value, checked

I'm new here and this is my first post. Please let me know if I do anything wrong, thanks.

Recently I'm working on an account management page using angularjs. I'm having a problem when setting default checked to gender radio buttons. I use bit in database to record gender and yes I've tried ng-value but it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```js
    var module = angular.module("MainApp", []);

    module.controller('GlobalCtrl',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.testerSet = [{ name: 'Ysoda', Gender: true, age: 9 }, { name: 'Lydia', Gender: false, age: 9 }];

        $scope.setCurrentTester = function () {
            if ($scope.testerCollection[0] != null) {
                $scope.currentTester = $scope.testerCollection[0];
                // $scope.$apply();
            }
        };
    });
```

```html
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>

            <div ng-app='MainApp'>
                <div ng-controller='GlobalCtrl'>
                    {{testerSet[0].name}}
                  <select multiple ng-model="testerCollection" style="width: 100%; height: 400px" ng-options="tester.name for tester in testerSet" ng-change="setCurrentTester();">
                  </select>
                  
                  <div>
                                                    <label>Gender：</label>
                                                    {{currentTester.name}}
                                                    {{currentTester.Gender}}
                                                    <label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="genderSet" ng-model="currentTester.Gender" ng-value=true id="radioMale" /> Male</label>
                                                    <label><input type="radio" runat="server" name="genderSet" ng-model="currentTester.Gender" ng-value=false id="radioFemale" /> Female</label>
                                                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I use multiple select to show a select as a listbox, I'm thinking that might be the reason why it doesn't work. I've spent hours working on this little button and I just don't know why names and account and all other data work well but the gender radio boxes do not.

I use {{currentUser.Gender}} to check value and the value shows correct. However, the default check still doesn't work.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: use value instead of ng-value..

Comment: <input type="radio"  value="" checked="checked" />

Comment: Your question could be stated more clearly...  From what I can tell from your code, the radio button doesn't have a 'default', it is only set when you select a user from the `select`.  When I fix your code and try it out it works fine.  Working example code is also a must, use jsfiddle or plnkr if you must, but you can add angular as a library in your sample and set the value manually instead of using `$http` which won't work...

Comment: As an example, your question could probably be stated: "I have an array of users and when I select one from a list I want radio buttons to display the selected user's gender appropriately but I can't get it to work."

Comment: Thank you very much. I apologize for my poor English, it's a little difficult to express my question, but I got your point and know how to make my question more clearly.

Meanwhile...it is embarrassing. To put my code up here, I wrote a example code, then I find out it works perfectly. So I guess the problem might caused my the CSS of the template.

Should I delete this post?

Answer (score 3):

```
<input type="radio" runat="server" name="genderSet" ng-model="currentUser.Gender" ng-value=true id="radioMale" /> Male
```

ng-value=*"true"* give the value without quotes  **ng-value=true**